# Cannot use tensorboard with Vertex AI Custom job

Tags: tensorboard, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to launch a custom training job using Vertex AI through [XManager](https://github.com/deepmind/xmanager). When running Custom jobs with tensorboard enabled I get a tensorboard instance in `experiments -> tensorboard instances` and a button on the custom job page that says `OPEN TENSORBOARD`. However, this leads to an empty page that says `Not found: TensorboardExperiment`.

- I observed this behaviour when running my own custom job and when running XManager's example [cifar10_tensorflow](https://github.com/deepmind/xmanager/tree/main/examples/cifar10_tensorflow). Note that in both cases the job runs to completion without problems.
- I can visualise the logs locally via the standard tensorboard package and passing as `log_dir` the cloud storage directory containing the experiments logs.
- I can upload experiment logs to Vertex AI tensorboard manually using

```
tb-gcp-uploader --tensorboard_resource_name \
  TENSORBOARD_INSTANCE_NAME \
  --logdir=LOG_DIR \
  --experiment_name=TB_EXPERIMENT_NAME --one_shot=True
```

- For more details check out the discussion: https://github.com/deepmind/xmanager/issues/15

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm running into the same issue